# Video playback works only as root using a Nvidia card

Tags: nvidia

That is, video playback with anything: chrome (html 5), firefox (flash), vlc, totem, smplayer... whatever. It works only if the software is started as root otherwise it freezes at the begin Interesting enough, in chrome, you can move the slider to whatever position and see the current frame updated.

However the video stay still. This started to happen a couple of days ago after an unidentified update. Relevant output from chrome run as normal user gives some hint:

```
NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0
```

No output coming from firefox or vlc

```
$ ls -l /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 0 nov  8 21:18 /dev/nvidia0
```

Comment: How did you resolve this? Did you change /dev/nvidia0 to be in group 'video'?

Answer (score 1):

Removing nvidia proprietary drivers and using nouveau. Also I had to purge all packages of nvidia proprietary drivers otherwise I was getting wrong resolution on the display.

Answer (score 1):

Normally your `/dev/nvidia0` should be accessible to the `video` group. If you executed Totem (or any other player) you will notice a line like this:

> NVIDIA: could not open the device file /dev/nvidia0 (Operation not permitted).

Normally, you should be able to workaround adding yourself to the group video and rebooting your system.

```
sudo adduser Hal video
```

Is really weird that the `/dev/nvidia0` file is owned by root.